# How to display $name Input that a user submitted in a form within a $alert when user pushes the submit button?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, phpmailer

I am stuck and hoping someone can help.

I am trying to get the user's input (their $name) to show in the $alert'' when user submit form. Example: User types in to the form the following: ** Name: Joe , Tel: XXX.XXX.XXXX , Email: Joe@example.com *** and pushes submit.

-- page refreshes and says. "Message sent Joe, thank you for contacting us!"

```
$mail->send();
     $alert = <div class="alert-success">'
                     <span>Message sent $name, thank you for contacting us!</span> 
                    </div>';
```

Comment: Please go find yourself a beginner tutorial that explains how to process form data in PHP. This is not a site to come to and get the absolute basics taught.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix your typos, like this:

```
$mail->send();
     $alert = '<div class="alert-success">'.
                     '<span>Message sent '.$name.', thank you for contacting us!</span>'. 
                    .'</div>';
```

Now that you have a template in `$alert` you will need to make sure that you display it. The simplest way to do so is to `echo` it, like

```
echo $alert;
```

But you may need to display it somewhere else than the current position. Also, PHP is a template language as well, so in some environments you can do something like

```
$mail->send(); ?>
     <div class="alert-success">
                     <span>Message sent <?php echo $name; ?>, thank you for contacting us!</span> 
                    </div>
<?php
```

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing yours wisdom with me! You not only answered the question but also did it in a way that’s not degrading or show that it’s beneath you (like the him/her above). I really appreciate you taking the time to educate me on this matter; you’re truly a blessing to this community! May all the success come your way. You made my first experience here a good outcome!

Comment: @Jasonzk1 I'm happy to help. The aim is to share knowledge and help fellow programmers who are stuck with a problem. Everyone was a beginner at some point, including me, so I do not really understand the arrogance that can be found in some comments. We are here to amiably help each-other.